# Dictionary __gt__ and __lt__ implementation

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, default

I've been experimenting with Python dictionaries and discovered that `__gt__` and `__lt__` are implemented for dictionaries.

I've tested them and it appears that they somehow compare the keys, but it is not quite clear to me how that is done; for example, I'm not quite sure how `{1: 1} > {'0': 0}` returns `False` (as a matter of fact, `'0' > 100000` returns `True` as well).

Is there any document with specifics on the implementation of these two functions?

Comment: Only in Python 2.x - in 3.x you'd get `TypeError: unorderable types: dict() > dict()`. Is your question about **dictionary** comparisons, or why strings are "larger than" numbers?

Comment: At the python repr (Python 2.7.9 Anaconda 2.2.0) i can type the following code:<br/>`tmp1 = dict();tmp2 = dict();tmp1[1] = 1;tmp2['1'] = 2;tmp2 > tmp1` and that returns `True`... I'm not quite sure how that's done...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation has a [section on comparisons](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons). In particular:

> Objects of different types, except different numeric types and different string types, never compare equal; such objects are ordered consistently but arbitrarily (so that sorting a heterogeneous array yields a consistent result).

The reason for behaviour like:

```
>>> '0' < 0
False
>>> 0 < '0'
True
```

in CPython is that the *"consistently but arbitrarily"* comparison method selected was to order alphabetically by type name, and `'str' > 'int'`:

> **CPython implementation detail**: Objects of different types except numbers are ordered by their type names; objects of the same types that don’t support proper comparison are ordered by their address.

This behaviour was [altered for Python 3.x](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons) and you can no longer compare heterogeneous types (or dictionaries, for that matter):

```
>>> '0' > 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    '0' > 0
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
>>> {'a': None} > {'b': None}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    {'a': None} > {'b': None}
TypeError: unorderable types: dict() > dict()
```

---

In terms of dictionaries specifically, they are sorted such that:

```
d1 > d2
```

becomes:

```
(len(d1) > len(d2) or 
 (len(d1) == len(d2) and
  sorted(d1.items()) > sorted(d2.items()))
```

*(you can see this implemented in the [CPython source code](https://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.9/file/753a8f457ddc/Objects/dictobject.c#l1792))*. So if they aren't the same length the "longer" one is "larger":

```
>>> {1: 2, 3: 4} > {1: 2}
True
```

if they have matching keys, the one with "larger" values is "larger":

```
>>> {1: 2} > {1: 1}
True
```

and if they have mismatching keys, the one with the "larger" keys is "larger":

```
>>> {1: 2} > {2: 1}
False
```

Comment: and dictionaries keywords are sorted before comparing them? As in, if I create a dictionary with mixed type keywords (str, int, etc), what keyword is compared with what?

Comment: It's not quite equivalent to `sorted(d1.items()) > sorted(d2.items())`; the lengths are compared first.

Comment: before item compare, it must do a key compare, as in: `sorted(d1.keys()) > sorted(d2.keys())`. For example `{'1': 1} > {1: 1}; ` returns `True`, while `{1: 1} > {'1': 1}` returns `False`. I guess the implementation has contains something like `if sorted(self.keys()) == sorted(other.keys()) then: return sorted(self.keys()) > sorted(other.keys())`

Comment: @LorenzoTrojan: Are you mixing up `items()` and `values()`?

Comment: yes... that's the sequence then: first it compare the number of keys/items, then it compares the sorted keys, and finally it compares the sorted items... (I guess)

Comment: @LorenzoTrojan no, it doesn't *"do a key compare"*; `items` includes **both keys and values**. If you want to look at the *actual implementation* for CPython, go to the source code.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: The edit isn't quite correct; you'd need a `len(d1) == len(d2)` check on the right side of the `or`.

Comment: Also, [here's the relevant section of the source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/4234b0dd2a54/Objects/dictobject.c#l1792).

Comment: The "equivalent" offered is slightly inaccurate. It is done intentionally *without* a sorting. [See Guido's commit message](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/a0a69b8b429f3d4c91f1c432247cfda017505976).